# Accessing Page Element Values from Repeater Eval Script

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

I have a C#/ASP page. It has a repeater on it. Within this repeated I need to be able to access on one of the iterations the value stored within a hidden field on the page.

I have gotten as far as the below script, but cannot figure out how to access the hidden field control on the page.

```
<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "in " HIDDENFIELD.VALUE : "" %>
```

Can anyone assist please. Thanks!

Comment: Now what is the problem? script giving any error?

Comment: Nope it works. I just don't understand the syntax required to access my hidden field on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of script as follow

```
<%# condition ? truepart : falsepart %>
```

You need `hiddenfield`'s ID

```
<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? HiddenFieldID.value : "" %>
```

Comment: @user1434739 : got it? Just use hiddenfield's ID and dot value.